# php date - check if it's under 1 month

Tags: php, validation, date

I am checking if a date is less than 1 months from now. I have this working like this

```
$enteredDate < date("Ymd", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+1, date("d"), date("y")))
```

but instead of this big line, I want to put this `date("Ymd", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+1, date("d"), date("y")))` inside a function and then just call it to compare $enteredDate < ....

is there any other easy way to do this check. I checked Checkdate but i couldn't use it here.

how would I do this by using a function? or  should I do the complete check inside a function and use that in places..please give me a hint.

Comment: Sorry, i have it as yyyymmdd format.

Comment: use what alex suggested, but you will need to use strtotime on enteredDate as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function lessThanOneMonthFromNow($unixTime) {

   return ($unixTime < strtotime('+1 month'));

}
```

Comment: Typo on `strototime`

Answer (score 2):

```
function lessThanOneMonth($date) {

   return (strtotime($date))>(strtotime("-1 month"));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer is right. But if you want to use your code, just put your code inside a function.

```
//Returns boolean
function lessThanOneMonthFromNow($enteredDate){
   return $enteredDate < date("Ymd", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+1, date("d"), date("y")));
}
```

Sample use:

```
if(lessThanOneMonthFromNow("20110428"))...
```